# TypeORM - Getter & Setter problem with joinColumns - Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined

Tags: typeorm

I created 2 entities User and Photo with relations. When I try to find all data of User with it's relations, I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined

It works fine as soon as I remove my Getter & Setter and set the properties to public access and removing the underscore. But I want to keep Getters & Setters actually.

user.entity.ts

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { Photo } from './photo.entity';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id' })
  private _id: number;

  @Column({ name: 'name' })
  private _name: string;

  @OneToMany(type => Photo, photo => photo.user)
  private _photos: Photo[];

  public get id(): number {
    return this._id;
  }

  public set id(value: number) {
    this._id = value;
  }

  public get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  public set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
  }

  public get photos(): Photo[] {
    return this._photos;
  }

  public set photos(value: Photo[]) {
    this._photos = value;
  }
}
```

photo.entity.ts

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Entity()
export class Photo {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'id' })
  private _id: number;

  @Column({ name: 'url' })
  private _url: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.photos)
  private _user: User;

  public get id(): number {
    return this._id;
  }

  public set id(value: number) {
    this._id = value;
  }

  public get url(): string {
    return this._url;
  }

  public set url(value: string) {
    this._url = value;
  }

  public get user(): User {
    return this._user;
  }

  public set user(value: User) {
    this._user = value;
  }
}
```

user.repository.ts

```
public async findUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
  return await this.find({ relations: ['_photos'] }); // photos (without _) isn't working as well
}
```